# How to write an ansible yaml file by clojure?

Tags: clojure, yaml

I have this simple ansible yaml file,it works fine:

```
--- 
- hosts: 172.16.10.104 
- tasks: 
  - name: ping 
    ping: ''
```

I use a clojure https://github.com/owainlewis/yaml to use clojure to generate this yaml file:

```
(defn -main
    [& args]
    (def data [{:hosts "172.16.10.104"} {:tasks ""}     {:name "ping",:ping ""} ])
    (def a (yaml/generate-string data :dumper-options {:flow-style :block}))
    (println a)
)
```

this code can generate the yaml file:

```
- hosts: 172.16.10.104
- tasks: ''
- name: ping
  ping: ''
```

it can't work,the "- name" have to beyond two character of "-tasks"

if I define data like this:

```
(def data [{:hosts "172.16.10.104"}  {:tasks ""} [{:name "ping",:ping ""}]])
```

it generate this:

```
- hosts: 172.16.10.104
- tasks: ''
- - name: ping
    ping: ''
```

it can't work too

I don't know how to write the clojure file to generate yaml file like this,Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting the `:name` map:

```
  (let [data [{:hosts "172.16.10.104"}
              {:tasks [{:name "ping"}
                       {:ping ""}]}]]
    (println (yaml/generate-string data)))
```

with result:

```
- {hosts: 172.16.10.104}
- tasks:
  - {name: ping}
  - {ping: ''}
```

Comment: Thanks,but why (def data [{:a "a",{:b "b",:c "c"}}]) can't work?in the ping.yml,the tasks can be a list,means it can have "-",but in a vmware.yml,it can't work,the task must not be a list

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might want to consider using github.com/clj-commons/clj-yaml. It’s the lib circle-ci uses for their yaml stuff